# Нужна ли запятая в этом конкретном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Маникюрный набор из 8 предметов, покрытых золотом." Начальник просит ставить запятую после слово "предметов". Нужна ли тут запятая? Уважаемые знатоки, как правильно?

Comment: Суффикс "т" бывает только у причастий: запятая нужна.

Comment: "Суффикс "т" бывает только у причастий: запятая нужна" - ась?

Comment: ась? - воронакумась: http://wordsland.ru/magiclanguage/suff.html

Answer (score 1):

Нужна, конечно. А в чем сомнения?

Причастный оборот, стоит после определяемого слова.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая действительно нужна. Запятая отделяет причастный оборот, который стоит после определяемого слова **"предметы".** Но при обратном порядке запятая уже не ставится: **покрытые золотом предметы.**

Comment: Пишите по-русски. Что еще за "определительное слово"?

Comment: Сержик, я с тобой! )))

Comment: Галина, оказывается Розенталь безграмотный. Он по-русски писать не умел. А вот behemothus - самый умный.

Comment: Серж, а что Вы Галине-то жалутесь? Бегемотус умный, не спорю. Но Галина-то причем?! Она вас русскому не научит, если вы "определительное" от "определяемого" не отличаете.

Comment: Это вы не отличаете. Читайте учебники.

Comment: Серж, Вы смешной мальчик. Но я здесь не за тем, чтобы Вам сопельки утирать. Посмотрите историю правок, там видно, что Вы написали и что Вам Ваша нянька исправила.

Comment: В глазах таких самоуверенных , как вы, все выглядят смешными. Чтобы я ни написал, это вам не дает право оскорблять меня и высказываться об мне в таком тоне. Посмотрите лучше на себя!